# Serilog Change Log Level on Exception

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, seq

Is there a way with the Serilog/Seq configuration to change the minimum logging level if the log contains an exception?  My use case is the Microsoft JSON input formatter, it logs at Debug level but if there is a problem with the input format, it will throw an exception which is caught and logged at Debug level.  I want to log anything that has an exception attached no matter the level.

EDIT:
Need to clarify, in production we only log our messages at Information level or higher, or Warning if its coming from framework code (System and Microsoft namespaces).  Looking for a way I can log if there is an exception regardless of level of the message.

Comment: Unfortunately, the min level filtering is hard wired quite deep so I think no - you'd have to change the min level for the given sourcecontext _and_ make sure the sink is trapping that level.

Comment: It doesn't "throw an exception at debug level". It throws an exception, which gets caught and then logged a debug level. What does it do with the exception from that point on? Does it rethrow it? If so, can you catch it there and log it as an exception? Or are these internal exceptions being swallowed?

Comment: The exceptions are being caught and logged at the debug level

Comment: And then what happens? Does it rethrow? Does it give any sort of indication externally (apart from logging) that something went wrong? All JSON libraries I've used (if they have an issue with parsing that they're unable to workaround) will let an exception bubble up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with Serilog, but comes with some major drawbacks, namely, *all* debug-level events must first be constructed, before the unwanted ones are filtered out. This is probably too much overhead in most cases, and you're better off just changing the level of the events that log exceptions to `Information` or higher.

To do it, though:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug() // emit the events
    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(le => (int)le.Level >= (int)LogEventLevel.Information ||
                                  le.Exception != null)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Hmmm ok, maybe I will file an issue with Microsoft to get them to change the level on the JSONInputFormatter.  Thanks for the suggestion, this might work temporarily as I am reviewing APIs.